# Create Lambda Function AWS for buckets adding to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

we have a requirement to create item in dynamodb table when a bucket is created using AWS Lambda, any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  (Hint: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html))

Comment: I don't think that's possible. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations) are all the current s3 events that you can listen to.

Answer (score 0):

As per amazon: "Enabling notifications is a bucket-level operation; that is, you store notification configuration information in the notification subresource associated with a bucket"

The previous statement quotes the AWS S3 Documentation [Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html). It implies that the bucket have to exist and it is over an specific bucket that you create and configure the notification event. basically: You can't produce a notification event on a bucket creation.

I would suggest as an **alternate solution:** to consider a scheduled process that monitors the existing list of s3 buckets and write a record to DynamoDB when a new bucket is created (new bucket shows in the list). The following : [Creating, Listing, and Deleting Amazon S3 Buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-buckets.html) illustrates some examples of what can be done using the Java SDK but the same can be found in other languages as well (see: ***List Buckets***).

***Note:*** You can look at the following tutorial: [Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) as one of the possible ways to to run a lambda on an schedule/interval.

Accessing the Bucket object properties can give you extra information like the bucket creation date, bucket owner and more (details of the bucket class can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/Bucket.html))

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating S3 bucket from lambda, then same lambda can add an item to dynamoDB. Your lambda role should have permission to add item to dynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this what you can do is, you can use  [cloud custodian](http://capitalone.github.io/cloud-custodian/docs/index.html)with lambda. 
In cloud custodian there is a way by which you can automatically add username tag,[enable encryption](http://capitalone.github.io/cloud-custodian/docs/usecases/s3encryption.html) etc while creating a s3 bucket with the help of this you can add your custom logic and insted to adding username tag etc you can use boto3 to add the bucket value to DynamoDB.